# Delegates and some way to see what is inside

Tags: c#, delegates

Is there any way to see what methods are in a delegate ??
I tried to find some information about it but I haven't bumped on any, beside only i know that I can check if delagates is null or not but, but what is inside?

Comment: `var toBeExecuted = myDelegate.GetInvocationList();`?

Comment: What do you expect to see? What problem you are trying to solve? Instead of using delegate type you can use own type, which will contains delegate and that something else what you want.

Comment: **Dmitry Bychenko** thank you It is what I were looking for. Now I use reflection to get the name of Method by MethodInfo().Name